# How do I look at my Facebook look back video again?

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

I looked at it yesterday and didn't share it.

But today tried to look at it again and it didn't show up?

And when I go to the URL it brings me to six photos of myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the same URL you used before: https://facebook.com/lookback/

Comment: I tried that.. it just brings me to 6 pictures of me!

Comment: @Veronica: Then please edit your question to include this important information.

Comment: OK.. I did!@Al E.